# Android recognize an integer from string

Tags: android, string, integer, type-conversion

Background: I have an app which uses `SpeechRecognizer`. Now I want the user to be able to speak in numbers, which should then be recognized by the program to act accordingly.
That is where the problem starts: `SpeechRecognizer` gives back a `String`, not an `Integer`. So, when the user says "Hundred", it will be recognized as "Hundred" and not as '100', which would be way more useful (for example in for-loops).

A solution I found myself was just to hardcode all possible outcomes and let them correspond to their numeric counterparts: "One" becomes '1', "Two" becomes '2', etc., but for 10 possibilities it's dirty, for 100 it's ugly and for 1000 or more it's undoable.

So, the question is: How can one convert `String` "One" to `Integer` '1' without having to type it explicitely? Can I give an option to SpeechRecognizer to only give back integers, or are there libraries out there that do this, or even just a standard function I missed?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Apparently my rigorous method of testing isn't that rigorous. Which means that I did not test it (correctly), even though I thought I did (oh the humility): `SpeechRecognizer` does not give a `String` back containing "One", it gives the `String` "1" back. Which is parseable by `Integer.parseInt()`, as someone commented just now but did almost immediately remove.

Sorry to have spilled your time, have a nice day.

Comment: You can break it into pieces and for 999,999 you wouldn't need any more than like 30 switches: "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety", "hundred", "thousand" are the ones I can think of. For example 827,321 would be "eight" "hundred" "twenty" "seven" "thousand" "three" "hundred" "twenty" "one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's neither a standard function of the speech recognizer nor of Java.

Manually coding the conversion actually isn't as bad as it sounds. True, everything from 0 to 20 is pretty much a hardcoded switch statement, but things get much butter after that.

Used to give the opposite problem (`int` to `String`) as a TDD coding exercise for people we interviewed for developer roles. You definitely get away with a single not-too-bad-looking converter class.

And, in response to the comment: You will need far more effort to make that parse *all* numbers (including mumbled words). This will rather be a proof-of-concept than something ready to role out to beat Siri / OkGoogle.

Comment: Aren't there large numbers, which can be pronounced in multiple different ways? Like "Five hundred and six" vs "fivehundredsix". Hm, at least I wouldn't feel very safe hardcoding stuff like this.

Comment: Agreed - but then this logic has to be _somewhere_, hasn't it? And I guess it makes most sense to have it on application level (as opposed to API level, because that would impose restriction on other apps that might actually care about "...six" and "...and six"). At the end of the day you would probably need a dictionary approach, but my understanding is that the OP is not there (yet).